# python request.get giving 403 forbidden whereas the url is perfect in browser. Why?

Tags: python, http-status-code-403, get-request

I have code to get the json of a particular webpage which requires authentication, as like

```
dummy_url = "some url with some parameter like offset"
obj = requests.get(dummy_url.format(offset=0),auth=("#MyUserName","#MyPassword"))
required_json = obj.json()
```

If I type the url in the some browser like chrome/firefox,I am getting the required page but if i use the above code then i am getting 403 forbidden error.

hoping for some way to solve it... :}

Thanks in Advance :}

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help:

```
   import base64, urllib2, json
   username = 'your_username'
   password = 'your_password'
   request = urllib2.Request(dummy_url )
   base64string = base64.b64encode('%s:%s' % (username, password))
   request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)

   response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
   record = json.loads(response.read())
   print("My JSON:", record)
```

***Link***

https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html

Answer (score 0):

Just as short hint, for debugging network protocols use wireshark and look about the information of your generated requests.